# Adding friendRequest in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

As i am sending friend request to other user which is in the user list i simply using this code for comparing login user and other non login user. but this code does not work.

```
<?php $userid=$this->session->userdata('userID'); ?>
<?php 
    if($this->session->userdata('userID')==$userid)
    {

}
else
{
    echo '<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/myinfocontroller/friendrequest" > <input type="submit"                  name="Friendbutton" value"Friendrequest" /> </a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is wrong in the else clause use this:

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/myinfocontroller/friendrequest"><input type="submit" name="Friendbutton" value"Friendrequest" /></a>'; ?>
```

Now the link will work!